# Cassandra: what is the correct configuration for EC2 multi-region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

What is the correct configuration for a mulit-region setup in EC2 instances?

What should the listen_address, broadcast_address, rpc_address and seed ip/addresses be to work?

When do you use public IP address and when do you use private IP addresses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370644/how-to-connect-datastax-dev-center-to-remote-cluster-in-amazon-ec2-instance/40189240#40189240

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=#cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html):

`broadcast_address`: (Default: `listen_address`) If your Cassandra cluster is deployed across multiple Amazon EC2 regions and you use the EC2MultiRegionSnitch, set the broadcast_address to public IP address of the node and the listen_address to the private IP.

`listen_address`: (Default: localhost) The IP address or hostname that other Cassandra nodes use to connect to this node. If left unset, the hostname must resolve to the IP address of this node using/etc/hostname, /etc/hosts, or DNS. Do not specify 0.0.0.0.

`rpc_address`: (Default: localhost) The listen address for client connections (Thrift remote procedure calls).

`seed_provider`: (Default: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider) A list of comma-delimited hosts (IP addresses) to use as contact points when a node joins a cluster. Cassandra also uses this list to learn the topology of the ring. When running multiple nodes, you must change the - seeds list from the default value (127.0.0.1). In multiple data-center clusters, the - seeds list should include at least one node from each data center (replication group)

Trying to summarize:

1. the `rpc_address` is used for client connections and has nothing to do with multi-region EC2
2. the `listen_address` and `broadcast_address` are the 2 important options for multi-region EC2 configuration
3. in general when configuring any of these answer 2 questions:

   1. who is connecting? (another nodes? clients?)
   2. what IPs are accessible? (is this network interface accessible to who is connecting?)