# How to connect datastax dev center to remote cluster in amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, datastax, datastax-startup

I have set the following.
rpc_address to external public ip. 
Listen Address : internal ip address (not the local host), 
rpc_broad_cast: internal ip address

On Dev center, I am using external ip and port 9042.

Let me know, if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thank you snakecharmerb for getting back to me. I am not able to connect and the error that I get on the dev center is. The specified host(s) could not be reached.
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /<amazon ec2 instance public ip>:9160 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/<amazon ec2 instance public ip>:9160] Cannot connect))
[/<amazon ec2 instance public ip:9160>] Cannot connect

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) for trying to help me out on this.

I was able to find a solution for this myself. The actual problem was I was using Dev Center 1.4 to connect to Cassandra 3. Once I upgraded to the Dev Center 1.5, it worked like a charm with SSH Local port forwarding enabled.

These are the following settings
Listen Address : internal ip address (not the localhost), 
rpc_address: internal ip address (same as above)

### Steps After setting the above steps

On my terminal enabled local port forwarding 
ssh -L 9042::9042 @

Start Dev Center 1.5

It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

It's worked finally :

steps :

```
1. set listen_address to private IP of EC2 instance.
2. do not set any broadcast_address
3. set rpc_address to 0.0.0.0
4. set broadcast_rpc_address to public ip of EC2 instance.
```